# How to convert a Multi-Choice to Single-Choice dialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I have the following code which gets multiple choices from user:

```
protected Button selectColoursButton;

  protected CharSequence[] colours = { "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Orange", "Purple", "MAGENTA", "WHITE", "SKYBLUE" };
  protected ArrayList<CharSequence> selectedColours = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    selectColoursButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_colours);
    selectColoursButton.setOnClickListener(test);

}

View.OnClickListener test = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
          case R.id.select_colours:
            // TODO: Show the colours dialog
              showSelectColoursDialog();
            break;

          default:
            break;
        }

    }
};

protected void showSelectColoursDialog() {
      boolean[] checkedColours = new boolean[colours.length];
      int count = colours.length;

      for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        checkedColours[i] = selectedColours.contains(colours[i]);

      DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener coloursDialogListener = new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
          if(isChecked) {
            selectedColours.add(colours[which]);
            dialog.dismiss();
          }
          else
            selectedColours.remove(colours[which]);

          onChangeSelectedColours();
        }
       };

      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle("Select Colours");
      builder.setMultiChoiceItems(colours, checkedColours, coloursDialogListener);

      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialog.show();
    }

protected void onChangeSelectedColours() {
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

      for(CharSequence colour : selectedColours)
        stringBuilder.append(colour + ",");

      selectColoursButton.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```

How do I convert it to make it Single choice only, once the selection is chosen the dialog closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(String[] items, int defaultPos, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know the way it's supposed to be written but how would I change the existing `builder` line?